# Tensorflow error when I try to use tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, convolution

When I invoke tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d the tensorflow execution terminates with an error about one of the parameters used

```
got an unexpected keyword argument 'weight_init'
```

The parameter passed are the follows:

```
layer_one = tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d(
    float_image_batch,
    num_output_channels=32,     
    kernel_size=(5,5),          
    activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
    weight_init=tf.random_normal,
    stride=(2, 2),
    trainable=True)
```

That is exactly as described in the book that I'm reading. I suspect a possible syntax problem with `weight_init=tf.random_normal` written directly inside the call, but I don't know how to fix. I'm using Tensorflow 0.12.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book that you are reading (You didn't mention which one) might be using an older version of TensorFlow when the initial values for the weight tensor was passed through the `weight_init` argument. In the TensorFlow library version you are using (You didn't mention your TF version), probably that argument is replaced with `weight_initializer`. The latest (TensorFlow v0.12.0) documentation for `tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d` is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/contrib.layers/higher_level_ops_for_building_neural_network_layers_#convolution2d).

To fix your problem, you can change the following line in your code:

`weight_init=tf.random_normal`

to

`weight_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer()`

According to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/state_ops/sharing_variables?hl=bn#random_normal_initializer), by default, `tf.random_normal_initialier` uses a 0.0 mean, a standard deviation of 1.0 and the datatype to be tf.float32. You may change the arguments as per your need using this line instead:
`weight_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(mean=0.0, stddev=1.0, seed=None, dtype=tf.float32)`

Comment: Now I get a similar problem with `hidden_layer_three = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
    flattened_layer_two,
    512,
    weights_initializer=lambda i, dtype: tf.truncated_normal([38912, 512], stddev=0.1),
    activation_fn=tf.nn.relu
)`  got an unexpected keyword argument `partition_info=partition_info` but there isn't any partition_info keyword in my code